# Javascript + onresize event

Tags: javascript

Why can't I add multiple instances of onresize to the window element? For instance, only the second onresize event (tire) will trace to the log:

```
var windowResize = {    
  fire : function(){ window.onresize = function(){ console.log('fire') }},
  tire : function(){ window.onresize = function(){ console.log('tire') }}
}
windowResize.fire();
windowResize.tire();
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? BTW it is because window.onresize can only hold one object at any time. it is not an array of event handlers it is AN event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@[Hemant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2488550/hemant-negi) is absolutely correct.

Another version of code in pure javascript is this.

```
var windowResize = {    
  fire : function(){ window.addEventListener('resize', function(){console.log('fire');}, false);},
  tire : function(){ window.addEventListener('resize', function(){console.log('tire');}, false);}
} 

windowResize.fire();
windowResize.tire();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of DOM default events can have a single handler attached to it. when you are registering the resize event second time it overwrites the previous value.

You can use jQuery or other library to achieve this, They can hold a array of handlers for a particular event and fire them all when the event occurs.

using jquery it will be like

```
var windowResize = {    
  fire : function(){ $(window).resize( function(){ console.log('fire')});},
  tire : function(){ $(window).resize (function(){ console.log('tire') });}
}
windowResize.fire();
windowResize.tire();
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

According with W3C, you cannot set more functions for same event handler.
You can use jQuery like this:

```
$('#foo').bind('resize', function() {
  console.log('fire');
  console.log('tire');
});
```

I hope I was helpful ^_^